# Schatten $p$-class operators between two different Hilbert spaces

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

It is well known that Hölder's inequalities in Schatten $p$-classes hold, that is,

> Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space.
> For $p \in [1,\infty]$, define Schatten $p$-norm by $\|A\|_{S^p}:= (\mathrm{Tr}(|A|^p))^{1/p}$.
> If $p,q,r \in [1,\infty]$ satisfy $1/r = 1/p + 1/q$, then it holds that
> $$\|AB\|_{S^r} \le \|A\|_{S^p} \|B\|_{S^q}.$$

By the way, Wikipedia(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schatten_norm) says we can extend the definition of Schatten $p$-norm in the following way:

> Let $H,K$ be two Hilbert spaces.
> For linear operators $A:H \to K$, we define Schatten $p$-norm by $\|A\|_{S^p(H\to K)}:= [\mathrm{Tr}_H ((\sqrt{A^*A})^p)]^{1/p}$.

And it seems that we can extend Hölder's inequality in the following way:

> Let $H_1$, $H_2$ and $H_3$ be Hilbert spaces.
> If $p,q,r \in [1,\infty]$ satisfy $1/r = 1/p + 1/q$, then it holds that
> $$\|AB\|_{S^r(H_1 \to H_3)} \le \|A\|_{S^p(H_2 \to H_3)} \|B\|_{S^q(H_1 \to H_2)}.$$

As far as I read the article on Wikipedia, it seems that we should read

Fack, Thierry; Kosaki, Hideki (1986). "Generalized $s$-numbers of $\tau$-measurable operators"
https://msp.org/pjm/1986/123-2/pjm-v123-n2-p03-s.pdf

However, this paper is too abstract to understand.
I would like to know appropriate references or easy proof for the above result.

Comment: What's your question? Do you want to prove that the inequality holds if $H_1,H_2$ and $H_3$ are different Hilbert spaces basing on the fact the inequality. holds in the case $H_1=H_2=H_3$ ?